# Internationalization with spring boot. Default messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

i want to provide the text on my page in a language the user understands.
Since i don't speak every language on the world and i don't trust google transalte that much ;) i want to use a default language.

I thought I could just provide every language i know in a messages_en.properties or messages_de.properties and for every language i didn't provide like this the default messages.properties is used.

It turns out that this is not the case.
The two explicitly provided languages do work as expected but if i try to visit my site when set my browsers language for example to polish, it shows german instead of english which is used in my messages.properties.

I didn't do any specific configuration to use internationalization. I just use the thymeleaf-starter and reference my messages by `th:text="#{my.property}"`

Do i have to configure anything to make messages.properties the default?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource.html#setFallbackToSystemLocale-boolean-

Comment: Thank you ;) just found that a minute after i asked the question. Sorry, sometimes I just try to formulate my problem explicitly in stackoverflow to make it more clear for myself. Hope that the answer will help others to find the solution faster :)

Comment: No problem. I upvoted your answer. This technique is well-known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay i just figured out what the problem was.

There is a property `spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale` which defaults to `true`. That's why the german messages were picked for a unknown language.
When setting it to `false` it defaults to the message.properties.